# Can we call roslaunch or rosrun through a web page?

Tags: ros

I have a question that can we call or run files of our package inside ros through a webpage. In other word, can we perform rosrun or roslaunch from an html page?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want is to integrate a shell to a website. There are some projects dealing with such use cases. A greate solution is shellinabox. It is [open source](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox), easy to use and install. With the shell integrated to a website you are able to perform all shell commands you need to control ROS.

You can find a nice tutorial how to install and use shellinabox at [Tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/shell-in-a-box-a-web-based-ssh-terminal-to-access-remote-linux-servers/).